# Using parbox in two column format

Tags: tables, parbox

I am trying to put two tables side by side in two column format.  But I am getting the error

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.  
>                      l l.460         \end{tabular*}   }

unfortunately it does not give me a clue on what is wrong.  Can anyone help me to fix the code below

```
\begin{table*}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
        \centering
        \caption{Data1}
        \label{tab:res1}
        \begin{tabular*}{l*{6}{c}}
            \hline \\ 
            Baseline &   SMC &  RMC  &  PMF  &  MOD  &  SCA  & RSR  \\
            \hline \\ 
            M1     & 0.641 & 0.772 & 0.333 & 0.314 & 0.305 & 0.356 \\
            M2      & 0.301 & 0.372 & 0.853 & 0.814 & 0.805 & 0.846 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}   }
    \hfill
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
    \centering
    \caption{Data 2}
    \label{tab:res2}
    \begin{tabular*}{*{6}{c}}
        \hline \\ 
          SMC  &  RMC  &  PMF  &  MOD  &  SCA  &  RSR \\
        \hline \\ %[-1.55ex]
         0.131 & 0.272 & 0.663 & 0.634 & 0.635 & 0.736 \\
         0.311 & 0.362 & 0.853 & 0.564 & 0.555 & 0.866 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}   }
\end{table*}
```

Comment: as error said, you forgot to define width of `tabular*`, i.e. you should wrote `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{*{6}{c}}` .

Comment: @Zarko `tabular*` without change of `\extracolsep` doesn't make a lot of sense. So maybe `tabular*` was only a mistake (because of using `table*`) and should be replaced by `tabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is solved by comments, however i would wrote your table on the following way:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \caption{Data1}
    \label{tab:res1}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
    \toprule
Baseline &   SMC &  RMC  &  PMF  &  MOD  &  SCA  & RSR  \\
    \midrule
M1      & 0.641 & 0.772 & 0.333 & 0.314 & 0.305 & 0.356 \\
M2      & 0.301 & 0.372 & 0.853 & 0.814 & 0.805 & 0.846 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    &
    \caption{Data 2}
    \label{tab:res2}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
    \toprule
SMC     &  RMC  &  PMF  &  MOD  &  SCA  &  RSR \\
    \midrule
0.131   & 0.272 & 0.663 & 0.634 & 0.635 & 0.736 \\
0.311   & 0.362 & 0.853 & 0.564 & 0.555 & 0.866 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
    \sisetup{table-format=1.3}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \caption{Data1}
    \label{tab:res1}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S}}
    \toprule
Baseline & {SMC}& {RMC} & {PMF} & {MOD} & {SCA} & {RSR}  \\
    \midrule
M1      & 0.641 & 0.772 & 0.333 & 0.314 & 0.305 & 0.356 \\
M2      & 0.301 & 0.372 & 0.853 & 0.814 & 0.805 & 0.846 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    &
    \caption{Data 2}
    \label{tab:res2}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{S}}
    \toprule
{SMC}   & {RMC} & {PMF} & {MOD} & {SCA} & {RSR} \\
    \midrule
0.131   & 0.272 & 0.663 & 0.634 & 0.635 & 0.736 \\
0.311   & 0.362 & 0.853 & 0.564 & 0.555 & 0.866 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

second example is with use of the `S` columns from `siunitx` package which align numbers at decimal points. since all numbers in table have the same number of digits, tables not differ. however, it may become handy if you have for example numbers with teo digit integer part. than you need to change S column format for example to `table-format=2.3` (where `2` is number of integer digits and `3` number of decimals).

Comment: +1 But for number columns I would suggest to use `siunitx`. And you should add package `caption` for correct the vertical distance between `\caption` *above* the tabulars.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, you are right. i thought that use `siunitx` at numbers with equal number of digits is somehow overkill :-)i will correct this asap.